# How to set the title of a SwiftUi Chart?

Tags: swiftui

How does one set the title for a SwiftUi chart?
Any suggestions for how to dig through the docs.
I'm having a hard time learning the ins and out of this framework

Nothing obvious in Xcode docs.

And the web interface is also hard to navigate.
I've tried searching it but it's not a great strategy.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts

maybe someone could suggest a strategy for finding relevant info in an Apple framework?

here's the essence of the chart in question

```swift
   Chart {
      ForEach(vm.wtrChrtData, id: \.self) { wtrDatum in
         BarMark(x: .value("hr", wtrDatum.timestamp),
                 y: .value("cups", wtrDatum.cups))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.blue1)
      }
    }
```

[image]

i could put a title above it use a `Text("some title")` in a VStack.

Comment: I don’t think there is such a concept as a title for a chart. The chart is the representation of the data. I think your best bet is to add Text like you said.

Comment: that's not a terrible solution...and it does make sense

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept as a title for a chart. I hope it will be added in future releases, but at the moment you have to use Text().